# Spacing before ToC, ToF, ToT, Bib

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, bibliographies, koma-script

For my dissertation, I am using Koma-Script, and I am currently looking for a solution to manipulate the spacing before the table of contents, figures, tables, and bibliography. Specifically, I want to have 5cm of spacing between the horizontal header line and the heading of the index.

I saw that there are suggestions to change the chapter command, however, I do not want to have this spacing for every chapter but only for table of contents, table of figures etc. Do you have any ideas?

Many thanks for your support! :-)

My MWE looks like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt, tocindentauto, bibliography=totoc, listof=totoc, final]{scrbook}

\begin{document}


\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage

\listoffigures
\cleardoublepage

\listoftables
\cleardoublepage

\part{part}
\chapter{chapter}
\section{section}
\begin{figure}
\caption{test}
\label{testfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the skip before the heading of a chapter by eg.

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=\dimexpr5cm-\headsep\relax]{chapter}
```

If this change should only affect ToC, LoF, LoT and other lists under control of package `tocbasic` you can use it as argument of `\BeforeTOCHead`.

Unfortunaly there is no bibliography in your MWE. So I guess that you use `biblatex`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,bibliography=totoc,listof=totoc]{scrbook}

\newcommand*\specialchapterbeforeskip{%
  \RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=\dimexpr5cm-\headsep\relax]{chapter}%
}
\BeforeTOCHead{\specialchapterbeforeskip}

\usepackage{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\defbibheading{bibliography}[\bibname]{\specialchapterbeforeskip\addchap{#1}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\part{part}
\chapter{chapter}
\section{section}
\cite{companion}
\begin{figure}
\caption{test}
\label{testfigure}
\end{figure}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

**Example with package `natbib`** (see comments below of my answer)

```
\documentclass[12pt,bibliography=totoc,listof=totoc]{scrbook}

\newcommand*\specialchapterbeforeskip{%
  \RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=\dimexpr5cm-\headsep\relax]{chapter}%
}
\BeforeTOCHead{\specialchapterbeforeskip}

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\renewcommand\bibsection{%
  \specialchapterbeforeskip
  \addchap{\bibname}%
  \markright{\bibname}%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\part{part}
\chapter{chapter}
\section{section}
\cite{companion}
\begin{figure}
\caption{test}
\label{testfigure}
\end{figure}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
First bibliography page
\clearpage
Second bibliography page
\clearpage
Third bibliography page
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

---

You can also patch `\chapterheadstartvskip`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,bibliography=totoc,listof=totoc]{scrbook}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\chapterheadstartvskip
  {\@tempskipa}
  {\ifspecialchapter 5cm \else \@tempskipa\fi}
  {}{\chapterheadstartvskipPatchFailed}
\makeatother
\newif\ifspecialchapter

\BeforeTOCHead{\specialchaptertrue}

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\xpretocmd\bibsection{\specialchaptertrue}{}{\bibsectionPatchFailed}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\part{part}
\chapter{chapter}
\section{section}
\cite{companion}
\begin{figure}
\caption{test}
\label{testfigure}
\end{figure}

\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
First bibliography page
\clearpage
Second bibliography page
\clearpage
Third bibliography page
\end{document}
```

Then you can also use to change the space before other chapters, too:

```
\specialchaptertrue
\chapter{Abstract}
\chapter{Introduction}
\specialchapterfalse
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, works like a charm. Apologies for not specifying the package which I use for the bibliography. Unfortunately, I am using natbib. I figured that there is a command \bibsection which should enable to adjust the spacing. However, I was not able to create some working code. I tried things like: \renewcommand{\bibsection}{\specialchapterbeforeskip\addchap{#1}} (with and without the addchap) and I also tried: \bibsection{specialchapterbeforeskip}. Do you have any ideas? Many thanks!

Comment: In the meantime, I figured that the following code works: \renewcommand\bibsection{\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=\dimexpr3.2cm-\headsep\relax]{chapter}\addchap{Bibliography}} However, I have now issues on the labelling of the headings. It shows the headings of the previous part instead "Bibliography". \markboth{}{} did not work. Any ideas?

Comment: I can not reproduce the issue. `\renewcommand\bibsection{\specialchapterbeforeskip\addchap{\bibname}\markright{\bibname}}` works for me.

Comment: Thanks! - I did not include the \markboth into the \renewcommand but added instead the \markboth into document itself!