# Lyx: add space before figure title in list of figures

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, lyx, labels, titletoc

How to add space before figure titles in list of figures ?
I'm using LyX Version 2.3.0

[image]

Adding the following code to the preamble yields the following error

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{4em}
```

[image]

For future reference: these two lines of code must be added **at the very top** of the preamble otherwise, the previous error might appear.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! [Spacing before ToC, ToF, ToT, Bib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/432714/124842)

Comment: Your note for future reference is likely a bit misleading, because I think that depends entirely on what else you have there in the first place. I should have asked about that before posting my answer. You obviously have something conflicting with `tocloft`, so it's possible that `tocloft` is not the best solution. What did you have there?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. that's what my document's preamble looks like:
`\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{4em}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}
\usepackage[]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[format=hang,font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{utf8}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{RoyalBlue}{cmyk}{1, 0.50, 0, 0}
\usepackage{tikz}`

Comment: Right, the problem was with `subfig`. Use `\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft}` instead of `\usepackage{tocloft}`. `tocloft` will then take extra steps to not conflict with the `subfigure` and `subfig` packages. (Similar to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/336617/.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Indeed, with `\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft}`, the spacing works even if I add it at the end of the preamble, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try going to Document --> Settings --> LaTeX preamble and add

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{4em}
```

Adjust the length 4em to something appropriate for your case.

Comment: This worked fine, the error appeared when I added these lines *at the end* of the preamble. when I added them at the very top, it worked, thanks.